# Styling an input field: adding custom buttons inside

Tags: reactjs, typescript, font-awesome, styled-components

I have an input which is intended to look like this:

[image]

I have used this code so far, using Styled-Components and Font-Awesome icons to repliacte this:

```
<Thing>
 1 <i className="fa fa-chevron-up" aria-hidden="true"></i><i className="fa fa-chevron-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</Thing>

const Thing = styled.div`
    border: 1px solid; 
    width: 50px;
    padding: 1.5px;
    padding-left: 7px;
`
```

This is what I am getting:

[image]

Not sure if this is the correct approach of styling this, as it seems to be overflown.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the number in any tag and give it a height of 100%

Other way would be to give `<Thing>` flexbox and wrap the font-awesome icons in a `flex-direction: column` layout.

Comment: Tried this, was getting buttons side by side instead of top-bottom

Comment: @SharathKamlekar That’s why you need flex direction column

Answer (score 0):

(Not exactly answer matching tags of your question.)

Have you considered using [native HTML number input](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number) instead?

```html
<input type="number" size="2" value="1">
```

Display will be device specific to some degree, but you'd get semantic and accessible number value control without re-inventing it in React.

Comment: Yes, it is like that by default. And I would like to change this for extra control and look.

Answer (score 0):

I think this can help you

```
<Thing>
  <FirstChild>1</FirstChild>
  <SecondChild>
    <i className="fa fa-chevron-up" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <i className="fa fa- chevron-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </SecondChild> 
</Thing>

const Thing = styled.div`
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    border: 1px solid; 
    padding: 1.5px;
`
const FirstChild= styled.div`
    min-width: 20px;
`
const SecondChild= styled.div`
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column; 
    align-items: center;
    padding-left: 7px;
`
```